# Show $S^2$ cannot have a smooth vector field with two zeros that are either both sources or both sinks

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

### Backround

I have just learned the Poincaré-Hopf Index Theorem which says that if $\overrightarrow{v}$ is a smooth vector field on a compact,
oriented manifold $X$ with only finitely many zeros, then the global sum of the
indices of $\overrightarrow{v}$ equals the Euler characteristic of $X$. This is great, but it may not be the whole story regarding the "rules" of which combinations of different qualitative types of zeros a vector field can and can't have on a given space.

### Particular Question

### Edit: my "particular question" assumed something that was wrong, so only the general question makes sense

For example, my intuition tells me that on $S^2$ one cannot have just two zeros where both are sources or both are sinks. But this is not ruled out by Poincaré-Hopf since index doesn't distinguish between source and sink in two dimensions. So how can we rigorously rule this out?

### General Quesiton

What are the key theorems or theories used for which combinations of different qualitative types of zeros a vector field can and can't have on a given space/manifold? I am generally interested in simple spaces such as balls and spheres (in arbitrary dimensions) and also cartesian products thereof. I am not so interested in spaces with complicated combinations of holes of various dimensions and so on. So far I have been reading Guilleman and Pollack's Differential Topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following vector field $\vec v$ on $S^2$. Using standard spherical coordinates $\theta$, $\phi$, and let $\hat u_\theta$ and $\hat u_\phi$ be the unit vectors in the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions, $\vec v$ is given by:

$$ \vec v =
\begin{cases}
v_0\sin(2\theta)\hat u_\theta +v_0\sin(\theta)\hat u_\phi &\text{if $\theta\ne0$},\\
0 & \text{if $\theta=0$},
\end{cases}$$

where $v_0$ is a positive constant. This vector field has only two zeros (at the N and S poles) and both zeros are sources (if you make $v_0<0$ then they are both sinks).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't understand. Sorry not super familiar with spherical coordinates. So $\hat{u}_\theta$ is the unit vector that lies in the x-y plane with angle θ where $θ\in [0,2π]$, and $\hat{u}_\phi$ is the unit vector that lies in the x-z plane where $\phi \in [-π/2,π/2]$? Then it sounds like your vector field is zero on a full arc from S to N: ${(\theta, \phi): \theta = 0}$? Isn't that an infinite set of zeros, not just two?

Comment: The variable $\theta$ ranges from $0$ at the N pole to $\pi$ at the S pole, so the $\hat u_\phi$ component is only zero when $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$, i.e. only at both poles. In other words your intuition about the zeros of vector fields in $S^2$ is not correct.

Comment: I see so there a limit cycle at the equator and everything is spiraling toward or away from it depending on whether $v_0 > 0$ or $v_0 < 0$. I will accept your answer eventually but gonna leave open for a few days because still wondering about the "general question": Besides Poincaré-Hopf, what other restrictions are there on what kinds of zeros a vector field can have on a manifold or other space?

Comment: wouldn't the form $v_0 \sin \theta ( \cos \theta\, \hat u_{\theta} + \sin \theta\, \hat u_{\phi})$ be more adequate?